# How to create a email subject line that is right to left aligned withe some left to right text inside

Tags: email, right-to-left

I am creating an Arabic email withe right to left text alignment,
the html part is fine but I need to make a subject line to the mailer withe
part of the text in left to right English.
the problem is the subject line will not render any css or html code and,
will be outputted in plaint text.
so in some email agents the English text is on the right and on some agents it is on the
left side of the text.
my question is how can I create a subject line that include Arabic and English in one line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably isn't what you want to hear but I don't think this can be done. Like you said, the subject line is plain text and does not support any form of formatting (you can't make it bold or italic either for example).

The position of the subject is dependent on the email client and in most cases probably also the localization of the operating system. Formatting of the subject can basically only be done by modifying the settings of an e-mail client, which cannot be done by an e-mail itself.

Comment: I have found an answer for this problem. 
edit the subject line in Microsoft Word, align the text to 
the right an adjust the text as you need it,
them copy past it to the subject line

Comment: Cool, that was unexpected :) What does the source code of the subject look like now? And on which e-mail client did you try it out?

Comment: @reuven Did not work in Outlook...